# Vuetify data table mobile breakpoint

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this vuetify data-table and I Want keep the same behavior on mobile resizing.
So I just want all in data on the same line.

https://codepen.io/sebastiancz/pen/JjoVRVg?editable=true&editors=101

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37
        }
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `mobile-breakpoint` prop to configure this. Value of `0` seems to disable different mobile rendering.

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
      mobile-breakpoint="0"
    ></v-data-table>
```

Comment: Excellent! Just what I needed!  Thank you.  You seem to be able to do just about anything with Vuetify!  What a great library.

Comment: Yes Vuetify is great, highly recommended!

Comment: In earlier versions you had to use `mobile-breakpoint="NaN"` because `0` didn't work. This was fixed in one of the more recent versions then. Hope this helps anyone who had the same problem as me upgrading

Comment: How would you do it the other way around? Always enable the mobile display?

Comment: @dari0h if I recall that is the default setting, so nothing to configure or set.

Comment: Ok, maybe I need to say a bit more. What I want is programmatically trigger the mobile/desktop display. And I'm doing this: :mobile-breakpoint="isSomeVariableTrue ? 9999 : 0". There must be a better way?

Comment: Vuetify has the following preset breakpoints, xs: 600, sm: 960, md: 1280, lg: 1920. VDataTable default is 600, so any of the preset options should theoretically just work.